# How do I resolve "No such Gstreamer factory: ffdec_mpeg4" warning?

Tags: multimedia, gstreamer, voip

I am using a multimedia VoIP client for making an VoIP call. The client is getting registered on the SIP server and the SIP call signaling is going through to another client but not the voice(although in wireshark I can see the RTP packets). When I start the VoIP client, I am getting a Gstreamer library warning:

```
No such Gstreamer factory: ffdec_mpeg4
```

I think because of this missing library the voice is not getting through. I searched in the Ubuntu repository but I could not find the library. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I just installed this packages and none of this problems appear, for more info try reading [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MediaCenter/CodecSupport) article.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras vlc smplayer
```

this programs uses tons of codecs, hope this helps